# Best approach to build and run with env specific values - Spring and K8S

Tags: spring, maven, kubernetes

Building a Spring based project deployed in kubernetes using Spring Cloud Kubernetes library with Kubernetes. The build is using maven and GIT CI/CD. Exploring the build process to package environment specific files and the runtime to pick up env specific files during execution. In traditional deployment, used to use maven profiles to build env specific libraries and configurations. Now spring has profile and maven has its profile. Besides, some of the designs includes files/configurations for all env included in the build and only a activated profile will use the correct configuration. Is it advisable to include all configurations in the package?

Is there a best approach on how these two work in handling env specific files or any other optimized approach to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that:

> In traditional deployment, used to use maven profiles to build env specific libraries and configurations

was never a case for maven profiles, if you take a look at [official guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) you may find following:

> Apache Maven goes to great lengths to ensure that builds are portable. Among other things, this means allowing build configuration inside the POM, avoiding all filesystem references (in inheritance, dependencies, and other places), and leaning much more heavily on the local repository to store the metadata needed to make this possible.

> However, sometimes portability is not entirely possible. Under certain conditions, plugins may need to be configured with local filesystem paths. Under other circumstances, a slightly different dependency set will be required, and the project's artifact name may need to be adjusted slightly. And at still other times, you may even need to include a whole plugin in the build lifecycle depending on the detected build environment.

> To address these circumstances, Maven supports build profiles.

So, maven profiles was designed to support codebase portability across **build environments**, but not to build artifacts for particular environment.

"Traditional" way to inject environment-specific settings into j2ee-application was to setup those settings via JNDI, i.e. j2ee-container was providing a configuration via JNDI and our application was consuming that configuration via JNDI. In case of spring/k8s/etc the main idea should remain the same: application knows how to retrieve configuration (system properties, environment variables, configuration server, service discovery, etc) and environment provides that configuration.

Comment: I completely agree with @Andrey B. Panfilov